# MySQL check if BLOB is valid UTF-8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, blob

I have data in `BLOB` columns in a MySQL database which I suspect is entirely UTF-8 encoded text (and therefore better stored as `TEXT`), but I would like to test this.

Is there a way I can check if a binary string is valid UTF-8 within SQL? So I can do something like:

```
SELECT SUM(IS_UTF8(col)) / SUM(1) as `percentUtf8`
FROM table
```

Comment: What client are you using?  It may be easier to read the blobs and test in a utf8 library.  Or there is a lengthy regexp that can be applied to hex(col) to check.

Comment: Yeah, I could pull all the data out and use `mb_check_encoding($data, 'UTF-8')`, but I'm looking for something that's going to be maximally efficient because I have hundreds of GB to go through.

Answer (score 0):

"Efficient" for you?  Or for the computer?  `mb_check_encoding` does it in a single read through the data--efficient for computer.  But you need to write the code to identify all the blobs, and do selects, etc.--less efficient for you.

Well, here is a way to generate the tedious part:

```
> mysql ... information_schema > sql.inc
SELECT  CONCAT('Foo("', table_schema, '", "', table_name, '",
                        "', column_name, '");'
              )
    FROM  tables
    JOIN  columns USING (table_schema, table_name)
    WHERE  column_type LIKE '%BLOB'
      OR   column_type LIKE '%BINARY%';
exit;
```

For me, `sql.inc` contained something like

```
Foo("test", "07", "md5");
Foo("test", "jpg", "jpg");
Foo("test", "key2", "stuff");
Foo("test", "picsav", "thumb");
Foo("try", "bin16", "bin16");
Foo("try", "bin16", "bin32");
Foo("try", "blobs", "b");
Foo("try", "f521951", "blob_c");
```

Then write the PHP `function Foo(db, tbl, col)` subroutine to do the test and display whatever you like -- or act on the result.  And do `require "sql.inc";`

Comment: As I said, I know how to do it this way. I'm trying to avoid the overhead of sending all this data over the wire from MySQL to PHP. It would be more efficient if the check happened entirely within the database server.

Comment: The regexp I suggested.